Confusion about finding optimal code in "Elements of Information Theory"
This is from Cover & Thomas, Elements of Information Theory, p.112:
"The preceding proof also indicates a procedure for finding an optimal
code: Find the $D$-adic distribution that is closest (in the relative entropy
sense) to the distribution of X. This distribution provides the set of codeword lengths. Construct the code by choosing the first available node as
in the proof of the Kraft inequality. We then have an optimal code for X."
The paragraph above follows the proof of the fact that the expected length $L$ of any instantaneous $D$-ary code is greater than or equal to the entropy $H_{D}(X)$, with equality if and only if $D^{-l_i}=p_i$. Later on, on the same page, they write:
"We proved that the optimal codeword lengths can be found by finding the
$D$-adic probability distribution closest to the distribution of $X$ in relative
entropy, that is, by finding the $D$-adic $\mathbf{r}$ ($r_i = D^{−li} /
\sum_j D^{−lj}$ ) minimizing... "
In the proof, they derive the equation
$$L-H = D(\mathbf{p}||\mathbf{r}) + \log_{D}\frac{1}{c}$$
where $r_i = D^{-l_i}/ \sum_j D^{−lj}$ and $c=\sum D^{-l_i}$. I understand that equality is achieved when the distribution of $X$ is $D$-adic. But the procedure suggests that if it is not, then we find the $D$-adic distribution that is closest to the distribution of $X$. I think that the idea is to choose $\mathbf{r}$ to minimize the right side of the equation above. But why do we only consider $D$-adic $\mathbf{r}$? Can't $\mathbf{r}$ just be any distribution that takes the form $r_i = D^{-l_i}/ \sum_j D^{−lj}$, where $\sum_j D^{−lj} \leq 1$ (instantaneous code)? My guess is that the RHS quantity above is always smaller for $D$-adic $\mathbf{r}$ than for non $D$-adic $\mathbf{r}$ somehow but I'm not sure how to show that. I can see that if $\mathbf{r}$ is $D$-adic, then the $\log_{D} \frac{1}{c}$ would be zero, but that's about it. Not sure what I'm missing here. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Edit:
I noticed that for a $D$-adic distribution to even be possible for $m$ codewords, we must have $m = Dn-n+1$, where $n \in \mathbb{N}$. If this is the case, then we can show that for any non $D$-adic $\mathbf{r_1}$, we can find a $D$-adic $\mathbf{r_2}$ that achieves a smaller value for $L-H$. We can simply multiply each $D^{-l_i}$ by $D^k$ for some integer $k \geq 0$ to create this $D$-adic $\mathbf{r_2}$. I'm not sure about the other case. Maybe they just don't consider it?
2nd Edit:
For the other case, I believe that we can just add dummy elements with probabilities in the form $D^{-k}$ for some integer $k$ until we have $m = Dn-n+1$ elements and then repeat the process above to create a $D$-adic distribution $\mathbf{r}_2$ from a distribution $\mathbf{r}_1$ which achieves a better expected length. So we should only consider $D$-adic $\mathbf{r}$ when trying to find a distribution closest to the source distribution in the relative entropy sense. (I think this is essentially what Huffman coding does.)

finding $$-adic distribution closest to the distribution of $X$ is generally hard
